# Unable to Open the SelfRegister page on Clicking Register User link

Tags: site.com

I have created a Login page using a custom template and added a Login form page element to the Site Page.

I have also created a SelfRegisterUser page and added a Self Register Page element to the page.

There are Forgot Password and Register User URL's in the Login form properties where I mentioned the URL of the SelfRegisterUser page (https://practice.force.com/customers/s/SelfRegisterUser) but on clicking on the Link on the Login form the SelfRegisterUser page does not Open up.

How can I solve this issue?